# appending to a file over SMB

Tags: command-line

In BAT, I want to do something like this:

```
echo LOGIN: %date% %time% %username% : logged in. >> '\\other-host\c$\logs\login.log'
```

But it doesn't work.  What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

it could be one of these ...

- host not reachable, can you ping it?
- file permissions, can you write to that file outside of a batch file?